# Broadcasting a message/event from a service (to all Windows sessions)

Tags: windows, events, windows-services

The Windows Device Management functions "provide a way to uniformly notify all applications and system components of changes that may affect their operation or access to resources".

I have a service that needs to provide notifications of certain events to any interested applications and services. This API looks like a perfect fit, because interested applications/services can elect to receive the broadcasts with RegisterDeviceNotification() and the sender doesn't have to keep a list of clients.

The `DBT_CUSTOMEVENT` event type seemed to be the right one to use, but that can be sent only by kernel mode drivers. Fortunately there is a `DBT_USERDEFINED`. The documentation says this should be sent using `BroadcastSystemMessage()`.

But then a colleague reminded me of "session zero isolation" in Windows Vista. Will `BroadcastSystemMessage()` of a `WM_DEVICECHANGE` be able to reach applications running in all sessions, as well as other services?

It looks like the question doesn't arise for kernel drivers because they use a [different function to send the message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463210). But my notifications originate in a service, not a kernel driver.

Am I barking up the wrong tree? I know I could use named pipes, but I really want a broadcast mechanism to keep things as simple as possible. I don't want the service that originates the messages to have to worry about where they are going. I also want to avoid third-party libraries. I want to do this the proper Microsoft-Approved Way and not re-invent the wheel.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644932(v=VS.85).aspx) you can include the `BSM_ALLDESKTOPS` flag which looks like it will be needed for what you desire. It requires the SE_TCB_NAME privilege, whatever that is!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (and the edits). It appears that SE_TCB_NAME is a very high privilege (http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showpost.php?p=441535&postcount=15) but also that the Local System account does have this privilege (http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30908514/interprocess-communication.aspx). I need to check this.

Comment: @Ian Local System is the most powerful entity on your machine. Use it with caution!

Comment: @David It appears that almost all services run as Local System by default. But I wonder whether Vista/Win7 limits the powers of Local System just as it does for Administrator… I'll do some tests.

Comment: @Ian UAC doesn't apply in session 0. Local System is just as powerful. Whilst many services run under Local System, you should not follow suit if you can avoid it.

Comment: @David With no other responses, I invite you to submit the suggestion in your first comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`BroadcastSystemMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644932%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) you can include the `BSM_ALLDESKTOPS` flag which looks like it will be needed for what you desire. It requires the `SE_TCB_NAME` privilege.

Comment: I won't now have a chance to try this for a few months, but I'm accepting the answer since it seems highly likely to be what I want.

Comment: This approach ultimately failed - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245082/use-of-broadcastsystemmessage-with-wm-devicechange-and-dbt-userdefined